# Align matrix correctly

Tags: matrices, arrays

I have a matrix with "description" of the Elements on the left side and on the matrix. So the matrix is in exactly the same row as the description, but the columns are not in exactly the same line as the description. How can I improve this?

```
  $\begin{array}{r|c}
  & \begin{matrix} A & B & C & D & E\end{matrix} \\
  \hline
  \begin{matrix}
  A\\
  B\\
  C\\
  D\\
  E
 \end{matrix} &
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}
 \end{array}$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX,SE! Perhaps you want to have a look at [`blkarray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution based on `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

 \[ \setlength{\bigstrutjot}{4pt}
 \begin{blockarray}{r@{\enspace\vrule}rccccc}
   \phantom{A}& & A & B & C & D & E \\
  \BAhline
  \begin{block}{r@{\enspace\vrule}r(ccccc)}
 A & & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \bigstrut[t]\\
 B & & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 C & & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 D & & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 E & & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \bigstrut[b]\\
 \end{block}
 \end{blockarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution with tabular and a "game" with its column widths

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}       

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|@{}p{0.007cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.6cm}@{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{0.1cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{0.15cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{0.15cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{0.1cm}}
 & &  A & B & C & D & E\\
  \hline
  A&\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\multirow{5}{*}{
  $\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}$
 }}\\
  B&&&&&&\\
  C&&&&&&\\
  D&&&&&&\\
  E&&&&&&
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]